# How to query firebase using list of keys in angular 7?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular7

I have list of keys which is retrieved thru a query. I need to query another firebase node using that list. How to do that in Angular7? Please advise.

Comment: Are you using realtime database or cloud firestore?

Comment: I am using real-time database